# How I can compare in R two columns of a matrix with two others and generate at the same time a new matrix?

Tags: r, sapply

I have a dataset:

```
time   delta
0.47   0
0.01   1
0.30   1
0.07   0
0.38   0
0.68   1
0.13   0
0.09   1
0.08   1
0.04   0
0.13   0
0.41   1
0.22   0
0.11   0
0.85   0
0.26   0
```

I'm using R and I need to compare this matrix with itself. I want to generate a new matrix 16*16 with values:

```
1 time_i > time_j  &  delta_i= delta_j != 0;

0 otherwise.

where i, j = 1,..., 16.
```

I tried to use the **sapply()** function, but it is useful only if I want to compare with respect one condition.

Could someone help me? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `outer` to apply a function to every pair of elements in two vectors, so you could do one `outer` for each of the two logical comparisons, combine them with a logical AND, then convert to numeric. Here I am assuming your matrix is called `m`:

```
1*(outer(m[,1], m[,1], `>`) & outer(m[,2], m[,2], function(x, y) x == y & x != 0))
```

This gives the following output:

```
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14]
#> [1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0
#> [2,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0
#> [3,]    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    1    1     0     0     0     0     0
#> [4,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0
#> [5,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0
#> [6,]    0    1    1    0    0    0    0    1    1     0     0     1     0     0
#> [7,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0
#> [8,]    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    1     0     0     0     0     0
#> [9,]    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0
#>[10,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0
#>[11,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0
#>[12,]    0    1    1    0    0    0    0    1    1     0     0     0     0     0
#>[13,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0
#>[14,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0
#>[15,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0
#>[16,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0
#>       [,15] [,16]
#> [1,]     0     0
#> [2,]     0     0
#> [3,]     0     0
#> [4,]     0     0
#> [5,]     0     0
#> [6,]     0     0
#> [7,]     0     0
#> [8,]     0     0
#> [9,]     0     0
#>[10,]     0     0
#>[11,]     0     0
#>[12,]     0     0
#>[13,]     0     0
#>[14,]     0     0
#>[15,]     0     0
#>[16,]     0     0
```

You can more easily check that the elements of the matrix are in the correct position by making a matrix of the rows and columns where a 1 is to be found:

```
which(res == 1, arr.ind = TRUE)
#>       row col
#>  [1,]   3   2
#>  [2,]   6   2
#>  [3,]   8   2
#>  [4,]   9   2
#>  [5,]  12   2
#>  [6,]   6   3
#>  [7,]  12   3
#>  [8,]   3   8
#>  [9,]   6   8
#> [10,]  12   8
#> [11,]   3   9
#> [12,]   6   9
#> [13,]   8   9
#> [14,]  12   9
#> [15,]   6  12
```

The first entry in this table tells us that the criteria were met for row 3 of the original matrix when compared to row 2 of the original matrix. It is easy to confirm that this is indeed the case.

Comment: Maybe a variant: `+(outer(m[,1], m[,1], ">") & outer(m[,2], m[,2], "==") & m[,2] != 0)`

Comment: That's very clever @GKi ,  - you're using automatic recycling of `m[,2]`, is that correct? All these years using R and I didn't realise you could replace `as.numeric()` with a `+` to convert a logical vector! That's why I love SO!

Comment: Yes, automatic recycling of `m[,2]` is used.

Comment: @Allan Cameron thank you very much! Excellent answer!